# How sql query can modify, such that repeating part is not displayed

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

This is related to our group project done at school.Our framework is codeigniter.

```
SELECT *  
FROM projects, task 
WHERE projects.projectname = task.projectname
```

The above sql statement merge project table and task table where one project has many tasks. We display result of above sql statement by using a table. this table has 4 columns as project name, client, task , task related employee. As project is having many tasks project name and client repeat in every table record. What we want to do it only show this project name and client only once and show task under that. How can I do that?
This is our view code

```
<table class="table table-lg" id="Table">
                <thead >
                    <tr class="filters">
                        <th ><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Project" disabled></th>

                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Client " disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Project Start On" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="End On" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Task" disabled></th>  
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" disabled></th>  
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Commission" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Task Start On" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Due On" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pause" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Stop" disabled></th>





                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
              <?php
                if(isset($view_data) && is_array($view_data) && count($view_data)): $i=1;
                foreach ($view_data as $key => $data) { 
                ?>
                <tr class="highlight" <?php if($i%2==0){echo 'class="even"';}else{echo'class="odd"';}?>>
                    <td><?php echo $data['projectname']; ?></td> 

                    <td><?php echo $data['ClientName']; ?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $data['datetimepicker20']; ?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $data['datetimepicker21']; ?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $data['task']; ?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $data['Description']; ?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $data['Commission']; ?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $data['datetimepicker21']; ?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $data['datetimepicker22']; ?></td>








            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'red')" /></td>


            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'green')" /></td>

            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'yellow')" /></td>

            </tr>


                <?php
                    $i++;
                      }
                    else:
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="7" align="center" >No Records Found..</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    endif;
                ?>

            </tbody>                
            </table>
```

Comment: using a table? that is UI problem not db problem, so Html? Window Form? Mobile iOs, Android?

Comment: Please be clear.. what do you mean by "display result using a table" ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I render the output using html.

Comment: @Krishnakumar using the above query i get results from database and show those result using a table

Comment: Then is your question how display a dataset in html?

Comment: Yes ..I was not sure whether there is a way in sql,,that is why i ask can I change sql, Is there any way I can get the job done using html?

Comment: You can, but is messy. And not recommend it. Anyway you should include some sample data and expected output in your question. Otherwise we will just be guessing what you need.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I add my view page for table

Comment: You show me what you have, but I need to know what result you want. Show me a picture with some data.

Answer (score 0):

This is not meant to be part of a select statement as the data is correct. It can be formatted later in your code or however you wish to display your data.